# How to fix the post method not working issue in Springboot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, post, keycloak

For the below controller, my "GET" method is working, but my post method is not working. The error is "POST" method is not supported. Getting 403 Forbidden error.

```js
@RequestMapping(value="/comments/submit", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String addComment(@ModelAttribute("comment") String comment, @ModelAttribute("blogId") int blogId, Model model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
{
    try
    {
        Site site = new Site();
        String returnString = responseMsg.getEntity(String.class);
        return "ajax.html.success";
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        logger.error("Exception in CommentsController.addComment()", e);
    }
    return "ajax.error";
}
```

Comment: Check if you are sending `CSRF` token in the `POST` request or not.